# When trying to wget openfire 3.7.1 it doesnt download the right file

Tags: wget

When trying to do a wget for [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=openfire/openfire_src_3_7_1.tar.gz). It doesn't download the actual file it should be getting.

When I did a vi on the file. It contained the following;

> " tar.vim version v28 " Browsing tarfile
>   /download-landing.jsp?file=openfire%2Fopenfire_sr " Select a file with
>   cursor and press ENTER
>
> gzip: /download-landing.jsp?file=openfire%2Fopenfire_src_3_7_1.tar.gz
>   tar: This does not look like a tar archive tar: Exiting with failure
>   status due to previous errors

Why doesn't wget get the right file?

Comment: What is the URL you're passing to wget? What happens if you put the same URL in a browser? Some generic advice: I have never had an issue with wget (but that doesn't mean you aren't). If downloading from a browser yields the same results as downloading from wget, that indicates there is either a problem with the URL or the server hosting the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the incorrect URL.

Try this one:

```
wget -Oopenfire_src_3_7_1.tar.gz "http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_src_3_7_1.tar.gz"
```

> Explanation: You were trying to download the landing page. The actual link above can be found on that page as "If a download window does not appear, please **click here.**"  `-O` just tells wget to name the output file sensibly.

Comment: Is -Oopenfire.. correct?

Comment: @DigitalFire: Yes, that correctly names the downloaded file. If you leave it out you get: `downloadServlet?filename=openfire%2Fopenfire_src_3_7_1.tar.gz` :)

Comment: hmm.. let me test. Seems like a typo

Comment: Seems to be downloading. How wierd.

Comment: Is the -O a switch for wget?

Comment: Yes; wget cannot intelligently name the output file when it's a dynamic URL, so we use `-O` to get a sensible filename.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Would of upvoted you but don't got enough rep. =[ Hope the community can reward you for me.

Comment: No big deal, glad to help.